# output specific array key for each result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i have a search engine for my page. as a result i would like to ouput the array key for each result.

so i have this code:

```
$results = search($keywords);
$results_num = count($results); //what shows the message how many items were found

if (!empty($errors){
foreach ($results as $result){
    echo "this is result: "
.$result['key'];       //thought would be the solution, its not.
    }
} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        $error;
    }
}
```

i also tried using a counter like:

```
$results = search($keywords);
$results_num = count($results); //what shows the message how many items were found
$counter = 0;

if (!empty($errors){
foreach ($results as $result){
    $counter++;
    echo "this is result: "
.$counter;
    }
} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        $error;
    }
}
```

what doesnt work as i thought and is still not that professional.
so if there is someone who could tell me how to solve this i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: to the part with the counter: it must be ++$counter; or $counter++;

Comment: What is the structuere of your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
  echo 'this is result: ' . $key;
}
```

The current `key` will be assigned to `$key` and the `value` for that property will be assigned to `$result`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

**edit**

In response to your comments, I think this is what you're trying to achieve:-

```
$i=0;
foreach($results as $result) {
  echo 'this is result: ' . ++$i;
}
```

Comment: this works great. just one more thing i would like to know. how can i set the start at 1 and not 0? thanks a lot.

Comment: You could skip the first iteration of the array using `continue`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: is there still another way? the first array[0] contains input. in case of using that the input wont be displayed.

Comment: Sorry I wrongly assumed you had a numerically indexed array, not really sure why as it wouldn't have made sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: i get the same mistake. it seems like continue easily jumps to the next entry in that array. so the first wont be considered.

Comment: Hmm I thought that was what you wanted? I think I've misunderstood what you meant by starting at 1 and not 0... can you elaborate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10428/discussion-between-deifwud-and-bonny)

Comment: no problem. okay: i get an array from the search funktion. this is like array( [0] => 'first entry' [1] => 'second entry') i will check for it in a foreach loop. so that i will display both results. for each result i like to dispay its array key. instead of the array keys below it should be:  array( [1] => 'first entry' [2] => 'second entry') or if possible untouch the array and rename 0=>1 and 1=>2 if you understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
//do something with key and value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here in code you can check first if `$results array is not empty because sometime due to empty $results array foreach generates error`**

```
/*Check if $results array is empty or not*/
if(!empty($results)){  
 foreach ($results as $key=>$result){
  /*result you want to show here according conditions*/
 }
}
```